# iOS Swift - making an object respond to pan/slide Touch Gestures

Tags: ios, swift, touch

I'm trying to make my first iOS game. Since I am new to programming, especially in Swift, this is being extremely difficult for me.

I am trying to make my cartoon eagle respond to my slide of a finger (What I want to do is slide my finger anywhere on the screen, and my eagle respond to that).

I've done it so that I can move it around but what I want to do is simply slide my finger anywhere on the screen and the eagle react to the movement of my finger.

Here is my code so far, I've linked this with PanGestureRecognizer, in storyboard:

```
  @IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x,
        y:recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're getting confused with UIKit and SpriteKit.

Basically, what you need to do is track your touches as they move across the screen. Since SKNode inherits from UIResponder, the easiest way to do this is to override:

```
touchesBegan(_:withEvent:)
touchesMoved(_:withEvent:)
touchesEnded(_:withEvent:)
```

For example to make the bird node follow your finger:

```
class YourScene : SKScene {

    var birdNode: BirdNode

    // Additional setup, etc

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
        if touches.count > 0 {
            var touch: UITouch = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
            var position: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)
            position = self.convertPointFromView(position)
            birdNode.position = position
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried it but I got this: Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'CGPoint'

Comment: I'm guessing it's because of the position!

Comment: Sorry I tried to do that too quickly. I edited my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Hmm..still getting that 'CGPoint' is not convertible to 'Double'that's because I'm doing this bird?.deltaPosY = position deltaPosY is a double

Comment: If you're trying to set individual coordinates then try: `bird?.deltaPosY = position.y`

Comment: Hi, I've updated my code. Managed to partially do it with storyboard, since for some reason I was still getting the same error in your code :( Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)

    if (touches.count > 0) {
        var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        var position = touch.locationInView(view)
        println(position.x)
        println(position.y)
    }
}
```